# Restore Files And Filegroups using .back file

Tags: sql, sql-server, filegroup

I have a database [Ordering_Live] and took the backup yesterday and today I restored this to another database Ordering_Live_Test using File and Filegroups option instead of database.
The data got restored successfully.
I had this as shown in the picture.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cm2uv.png
I still have my live database with all the records but my doubt is how it worked and .mdf didn't change when  it was restored using .bak file from yesterday.